# allowing pop ups with a alert

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to get so that when a user clicks ok on the alert, it will allow pop ups for my site. My current code is:

```
var w = window.open( "urls","_blank", "height = 200, width = 300, top=450, left=1025" );
if(w == null || typeof(win) == "undefined" || win.location.href == 'about:blank') {
alert("You must allow pop ups before continuing, click the button to allow pop ups");
}
```

How may i achieve this please or if not possible, how can i achieve a way so that they can allow pop ups for my site easily with out having to ask them to allow by going in to the browsers settings.

Many thanks

Comment: This is a browser security setting - you can't change it programmatically.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks, so in other words, there is no way i can have a button that will allow visitors to allow pop ups for my site. The visitors have to do it manually with in their browse settings, is that correct?
If this is correct, is their anyway i can redirect them to another page using the header function?

Comment: I've found that using basically anything other then `onclick()` will cause a popup message. As far as redirecting them to another page, you could use something like `window.location.assign('http://www.example/com');`

Comment: Instead of popping up a window, you can always pop-up a div. Appropriately styled, and with suitable event handling, a popup div can do almost anything a window can do.

Comment: Ask yourself, do you REALLY need popups that badly?  A user will normally turn them off if they don't like them and now you want them back?  Keep them for important reminders and make sure it only hurts the user if they don't have them on.  Their choice after all...

Comment: Thankyou all for your answers as they are much appreciated. The pop ups are random websites that we have themed or done some work to and open in a new tab when clicked on a link. As it opens a random one it causes the pop up blocker to kick in so i wanted to make it easier for my visitors to be able to allow pop ups from my website. As Robert said, pop ups are annoying but my visitors know that this will happen so its not too bad. I just want to make visitors life easy on having a button to click that allows pop ups. I saw this: <a href="#" onclick="allow_popups(); return false;"> dosent work

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just randomize the href in the anchor tag?
Es:

```
<a href="" id="randLink" target="_blank">Open a random site</a>
```

Imagine a jquery function that:
when the page is first loaded chooses one of your random sites and puts the link in the href of #randLink:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randLink').attr('href',generateRandUrl());
});
```

and that on each click, changes the href value:

```
$( "#randLink" ).click(function() {
 $('#randLink').attr('href',generateRandUrl());
});
```

generateRandUrl() is a function that returns the string value of one of your websites